# Magento 2.1 Discontinue Date

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Looks like Magento has recently announced that it is discontinuing updating Magento 2.0.

> Magento 2.0.18 is the final 2.0.x release. After March 2018, Magento
>   2.0.x will no longer receive security patches, quality fixes, or documentation updates. To maintain your site's performance, security,
>   and PCI compliance, upgrade to the latest version of Magento.

Has anyone in the community heard if they plan on doing the same with 2.1 as they are with 2.0 within a similar timeline? It's not the easiest of upgrades from 2.1 to 2.2 and would be a little grateful if there any information on this at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version lifetime and support table can be found here: https://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise-agreement#support

Magento 2.1 end of support date is **June 2019**.
Magento 2.2 end of support date is **September 2019**.

Magento 2.3 has yet to be released, but will be supported through at least April 2020 (it'll be two years past release, whenever that is).